# Selecting only distinct values from 2 columns in sql

Tags: sql, distinct-values

I have a Table in my database. I need only 2 columns from that entire database. Also, I need the distinct values from the two columns. The data is as follows:

```
ID          DATE
00432CDE    1/4/2016
64031QCL    1/4/2016
64031QCL    1/5/2016
64031QCL    1/6/2016
817176AA    1/4/2016
817176AA    1/5/2016
55818FAN    1/4/2016
55818FAN    1/5/2016
92912QAA    1/4/2016
92912QAA    1/5/2016
532621AA    1/4/2016
532621AA    1/5/2016
05344AAN    1/4/2016
05344AAN    1/5/2016
17305EFN    1/4/2016
```

As you can see there are multiple date values and because of that IDs are duplicated. I want to write a code where I can get the last date along with the ID. So the columns should look like this:

```
ID          DATE
00432CDE    1/4/2016
64031QCL    1/6/2016
817176AA    1/5/2016
55818FAN    1/5/2016
92912QAA    1/5/2016
532621AA    1/5/2016
05344AAN    1/5/2016
17305EFN    1/4/2016
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far???  Show your attempt!!  Queries don't get any simpler than this.  If you don't even bother to try, how are you going to improve???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an aggregate on your `DATE` column to choose which one to display. You want `MAX()`:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(DATE)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Note: Grouping by all non-aggregated columns achieves the same result as `DISTINCT`, so you won't need the `DISTINCT` keyword.